# Create a list of html() elements

Tags: r, list, rvest

The problem is, I'm sure, is rather simple. But I can't figure out how to make it work. I have four websites like so :

```
require(xml2)
require(rvest)
html1 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=4&topdomainid=2&subdomainid=6&last=0&orderby=6")

html2 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=3&topdomainid=2&subdomainid=6&last=0&orderby=6")

html3 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=3&topdomainid=2&subdomainid=7&last=0&orderby=6")

html4 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=4&topDomainID=2&subDomainID=7&last=0&orderby=6")

htmlPages <- c(html1,html2,html3,html4)
```

I'm trying to place them all inside of a list for easy access inside a for loop or something. Placing them inside the list is no problem. The problem is accessing them later. What I mean by that is I get fetch the text from the nodes anymore.

```
    getCSSElementText <- function(htmlpage, CSSElement)
{
  #Return a vector of the text values of the CSS element the function is looking for

  cssNodes <- html_nodes(htmlpage, CSSElement)
  cssValues <- html_text(cssNodes)
  return(cssValues)
}
```

As I call

`getCSSElementText(htmlPages[1], #properCSSTag#)`

I get this error :

> Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
>     no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "list"

Here is my whole code just in case something went wrong somewhere else :

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
html1 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=4&topdomainid=2&subdomainid=6&last=0&orderby=6")
html2 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=3&topdomainid=2&subdomainid=6&last=0&orderby=6")
html3 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=3&topdomainid=2&subdomainid=7&last=0&orderby=6")
html4 <- html("http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=4&topDomainID=2&subDomainID=7&last=0&orderby=6")
htmlPages <- c(html1,html2,html3,html4)

CSSElementIDs <- c("#ctl00_MainContent_divRankList a", ".staticOrderCol:nth-child(3)", ".staticOrderCol:nth-child(4)")

getCSSElementText <- function(htmlpage, CSSElement)
{
  #Return a vector of the text values of the CSS element the function is looking for

  cssNodes <- html_nodes(htmlpage, CSSElement)
  cssValues <- html_text(cssNodes)
  return(cssValues)
}

getCSSElementNumber <- function(htmlpage, CSSElement)
{
  #Return a vector of numbers with proper formatting etc from the CSS element the function is looking for
  cssNodes <- html_nodes(htmlpage, CSSElement)
  cssValues <- html_text(cssNodes)
  parsedCssValues <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", cssValues))
  return(parsedCssValues)
}

addToDataFrame <- function(df, vector)
{
  df[deparse(substitute(vector))] <- vector
  return(df)
}
```

Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: Try `htmlPages <- list(html1,html2,html3,html4)` and then 
`getCSSElementText(htmlPages[[1]], #properCSSTag#)` (two square brackets).

Comment: `html()` is deprecated, use `read_html`

Comment: Generally the simplest way to deal with this situation is to make a vector of URLs (or what you need to do so), and loop across it with `lapply` or `purrr:map` or variants. Start in parallel from the beginning, not halfway through.

Comment: Weihuang Wong's answer worked wonderfully. Thanks for your time guys, I'll look into using html_read instead, but when I tried it, it stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate your `html*` objects (which are each lists of length 2), they become a list of 8:

```
htmlPages <- c(html1,html2,html3,html4)
str(htmlPages)
# List of 8
#  $ node:<externalptr> 
#  $ doc :<externalptr> 
#  $ node:<externalptr> 
#  $ doc :<externalptr> 
#  $ node:<externalptr> 
#  $ doc :<externalptr> 
#  $ node:<externalptr> 
#  $ doc :<externalptr>
```

Instead, put the `html*` objects into a list:

```
htmlPages <- list(html1,html2,html3,html4)
str(htmlPages)
# List of 4
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

and access them with `[[`:

```
htmlPages[[1]]
# {xml_document}
# <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
# [1] <head id="Head1">\n  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  ...
# [2] <body onpageshow="document.forms['aspnetForm'].reset();">&#13;\n    <form ...
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much ! I'll look into using the html_read instead to get rid of the deprecated warning, should it work the same way ?